# Access other path parameters in Flask URL converter

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I'd like to create some custom URL converters for a Flask app. The resources are mapped to ORM models. I'd like to be able to access previous URL path parameters to determine relationships when doing the conversions. Is something like this possible?

```
class CustomObject1Converter(BaseConverter):
    def to_python(self, value):
        obj = Obj1.get_by(id=value)
        return obj

class CustomObject2Converter(BaseConverter):
    def to_python(self, value):
        # somehow get access to object1 path parameter here
        obj2 = Obj2.query.filter(Obj2.obj1 == obj1).filter(obj2.id == value).first()
        return obj2

app.url_map.converters['object1'] = CustomObject1Converter
app.url_map.converters['object2'] = CustomObject2Converter

app.route('/objects1/<object1:object1>/objects2/<object2:object2>')
def get_object_2(object1, object2):
    # do some things and return some data
    ...
```

Comment: why not use JSON for this? it seems like that might be the better thing for something like this.

Comment: @wgwz I don't get your meaning, I'm trying to take an ID from a url parameter, and turn it into a sqlalchemy object, but I'd like access to previous parameters in the path, so that I can validate that the relationship between obj1 and obj2 are valid. This would also allow me to consolidate error handling and query code into one place, instead of repeating at every endpoint. Seems like something `BaseConverter` should be able to do, but after reading the code, it seems that it isn't so.

Comment: what are you trying to do at a high-level?